# How to create a TableView with list [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]?

Tags: ios, tableview, nstimezone

My question is in the title. I just want to have the list of all the cities in the world (422 objects) and I have only examples with data written one by one with "add object".

I do hope there is another trick for my lazy fingers !

I have create this but it doesn't match.

```
  NSArray * timeZones = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
 maListe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// création dictionnaire
NSDictionary *tampon = [NSDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *aLocation in timeZones)

     {
    NSArray *continentsCountryCity = [aLocation componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];


    if ([continentsCountryCity count] >= 2)
         {

        NSMutableArray *continentPickerView = [continentsCountryCity objectAtIndex:0];
        NSMutableArray *villePickerView = [continentsCountryCity objectAtIndex:1];
        [tampon setObject:villePickerView forKey:continentPickerView];

         }
     }
```

maListe = tampon.allKeys;

Does anybody have a solution ?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: See Apple's sample table view apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_48. The 4th one in that sample does all the timezone stuff.

Comment: I have seen this tuto but they put some code in appDelegate and I still have one because the table will be add to other views. I don't know how to manage two appDelegates. I should normally have only one, that's it ?